# Нужны ли здесь запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

В ряде случаев эксплуатации глубиннонасосных скважин, с преобладающими в них парафиновыми образованиями, имеются разнообразные способы их удаления и предотвращения последующего образования в скважине.

Answer (score 1):

(Здесь надо обойти "образование образований")

При эксплуатации глубиннонасосных скважин на случаи возникновения в них обильных парафиновых образований имеются разнообразные способы их удаления, предотвращающие повторное их появление.

Answer (score 0):

> Нужны ли здесь запятые?

Может, будут нужны, может -- нет... Но сначала предложение нужно внятно сформулировать!

**Полная абракадабра!**